# Filling javafx V/HBox with x anchorPanes

Tags: javafx, fxml, fxmlloader

I'm currently working on a little project for a class using javafx for the UI.
I was able to display the data i wanted to show using TableView without any problems but since i've got some time left (and want to learn more) i want to spice things up a little.

A Nurse/Staffmember should have up to 10 rooms assigned to him/her, showing some Information.
My idea was to create a Vbox and fill it with up to 10 AnchorPanes displaying some labels.

```
    public void showRoomInfo() {
    try {
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
        loader.setLocation(Main.class.getResource("view/RoomInfo.fxml"));
        VBox roomInfo = (VBox) loader.load();
        staffLayout.setLeft(roomInfo);
```

//...

```
    roomInfo.getChildren().add(singleRoom);

    } catch....
}
```

I'm not asking you to do my work but I'm not sure if i'm even on the right track here.
Is there another/ a better way to do it?
Do you have any links to lectures/examples that could help me?

Thanks, I would really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using ListView?  You can use a ListView and populate it with a whatever UI element you want.  For instance, you could make a ListView of Labels, a ListView of HBox, a list View of Buttons, etc.  ListView will also give you the ability to select on or multiple Items in the list.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/user-interface-tutorial/list-view.htm#CEGGEDBF